# Setup Crontab to work with Cucumber

Tags: mac, crontab

I'm trying to setup crontab to work with cucumber. So far, I were able to get crontab to execute a ruby command, but not a cucumber command.

This is what I have in crontab:

- - - - - ~/test.sh > ~/out.log 2> err.log

If I do this in test.sh, it works fine:

/Absolute-path-to-ruby ~/test.rb

However, if I do this in test.sh, it failed:

/Absolute-path-to-cucumber ~/test.feature

This is what it prints out in the err.log:

no such file to load -- capybara/cucumber (LoadError)

However, if I run the test.sh (/Absolute-path-to-cucumber ~/test.feature) in the terminal, it works no problem.

---

So, I'm thinking that cron and the terminal are not using the same version of ruby (hence, an environment problem).

When I did a $ruby -rpp -e 'pp ENV' in the terminal, it gave me this:

"_"=>"/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby"

When I did the same command in cron, it gave me this in the log file:

"_"=>"/usr/bin/ruby"

So, it looks like cron is using the system ruby (1.8.7) while the terminal is using the user ruby (1.9.3). I have been trying all kinds of stuff that I could find to get cron to use ruby 1.9.3, but I have no luck so far.

Would any body give me any hint or pointer as to how to proceed next? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

cron's default path is `/usr/bin:/bin` and the default shell is `/bin/sh`. It doesn't read any configuration files like .bash_profile.

Could you just add `. ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` to the script?

Or `bash -lc` would start a login shell which reads configuration files like .bash_profile.

```
* * * * * bash -lc '~/test.sh > ~/out.log 2> ~/err.log'
```